# Can I change the attributes of a module at runtime in the active python shell?

Tags: python, module

Can I change the attributes of a module at runtime in the active python shell? For example, say I first start a python shell in my terminal. Then I import a module called functionBundle.py. Let's say there is some function f1 I want to use, which takes only one parameter. So I will write functionBundle.f1(parameter). Now, it is possible to redefine this function at runtime in the active shell? For example, if I write:

```
def functionBundle.f1(parameter):
    something....
```

in the shell, will this get me the desired outcome? How about values in the module?

Comment: You can, and your new version will be used from then on.

Comment: @Selcuk So does it also permanently change my module file?

Comment: No, it will only be valid during your interactive session. You are not actually modifying the `.py` file.

Comment: You cannot make it permanent without modifying the original module, but you can write your own module that wraps / extends an existing module.  See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It's definitely possible. But those changes are in effect for that interactive session, as @Selcuk has mentioned.

Eg.

```
## myModule.py
def printHello():
   print "hello"

## otherModule
import myModule
print myModule.printHello()  ## prints hello

def otherPrint():
   print "Hello world"

myModule.printHello = otherPrint
myModule.printHello()  ## prints Hello world
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extend or modify the behavior of another module in a readily reusable module, do it in your own new module.

For example...

**mymath.py**

```
 from math import *

 # A dumb example....
 def sqrt(x):
     return x
```

Code that uses new module:

```
import mymath as math

# will return 10, because it calls our new,broken sqrt.
math.sqrt(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can monkeypatch modules.
Assume that the original `f1` is the identity function.

```
>>> import functionBundle
>>> functionBundle.f1('returns input')
'returns input'
>>> functionBundle.f1 = lambda: 'hi'
>>> functionBundle.f1()
'hi'
```